# Dependencies Between Modules - Controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

This tells AngularJS that all values, factories and services defined inside the myUtilModule should be available inside the myOtherModule module too. In other words, myOtherModule depends on myUtilModule.

```
var myUtilModule = angular.module("myUtilModule", []);

myUtilModule.value  ("myValue"  , "12345");


var myOtherModule = angular.module("myOtherModule", ['myUtilModule']);

myOtherModule.controller("MyController", function($scope, myValue) {

});
```

My question is: What if you define controllers inside myUtilModule and try to use them on myOtherModule. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, controllers will also be available between modules, a pratical example could be as follows:

```
angular.module('test.controllers').controller('HomeCtrl');
```

and then on your main module:

```
angular.module('test', [
    'test.controllers',
    'test.services',
    ...
];
```

This helps a lot on unit testing and reusability of packages.